# If "smell" is to "reek", then "taste" is to "?"

Tags: single-word-requests

If "reek" is used as a term to describe something that smells bad, what word of equivalent meaning would describe something that tastes bad?

Comment: unsavory, unappetizing, unpalatable

Comment: You do realise that *smell* has more than one meaning?

Comment: 'Reek' means 'have / give off a terrible smell'.  I'm not sure there is a one word replacement (verb) for 'have a terrible taste'.

Comment: There are different words, according to the type of taste e.g. bitter, sickly, salty, etc. Recently I was given some salad in a restaurant which I told the waiter tasted *sanitised*. It had apparently been washed in a food-sanitising fluid - yuk. Hey, that's the word you want - *yuk*!.

Comment: ***foul***, ***rotten***

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps "**smack**" would serve.  This meaning of the word is defined by [oxforddictionaries.com](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/smack) as

> Have a flavour of; taste of

and

> Suggest the presence or effects of (something wrong or unpleasant)

Comment: I’ve always used *smack* with a noun: “it smacks of <something>” but have never said, “it smacks” the way you can say, “it reeks”

Answer (score 1):

> “smell” : “***reek***”
>   “taste” : “***smack***”

There is no one word that works everywhere, but ***smack*** is a perfect replacement in the compound verb *reeks of*:

> Your plan *reeks of* desperation. (*bad-smell metaphor*)
>   Your plan *smacks of* desperation. (*bad-taste metaphor*)

#### Acknowledgements

“[Words related to taste](http://www.lexfn.com/l/lexfn-cuff.cgi?sWord=taste&tWord=&query=show&maxReach=2&Atrg=on&Asyn=on&Agen=on&Aspc=on&Acom=on&Apar=on&Abox=on&Abnx=on&Abbx=on&Abdx=on&Abtr=on&Abak=on)” at Lexical FreeNet
Connected Thesaurus
“[define smack](https://www.google.com/webhp?q=define%20smack)” at Google
“[smack of](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/us/dictionary/american/smack-of)” at Macmillan Dictionary

Answer (score 0):

**Bite**. Often implies acidity, but works for any strong flavor.

> 3A sharp or pungent flavour. ‘a fresh, lemony bite’

ODO bite:  https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/bite

Answer (score 0):

You're probably used to this in a different sense, but [disgusting](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/disgusting) means

> causing disgust; offensive to the physical, moral, or aesthetic taste.

The etymology of [disgust](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=disgust) is "dis + taste"; in other words, it tastes so bad that feels repugnace toward it.

> 1590s, from Middle French desgoust "strong dislike, repugnance," literally "distaste" (16c., Modern French dégoût), from desgouster "have a distaste for," from des- "opposite of" (see dis-) + gouster "taste," from Latin gustare "to taste" (see gusto).

Answer (score 0):

Just from the limited information given by the OP, he/she seems to be asking for a verb for taste with a negative connotation.

> smell : reek :: taste : _________

Taking the general meaning of "reek" as "smell bad," a comparable verb that, when used for taste, generally means "taste bad" is [**cloy**](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/cloy):

> Disgust or sicken (someone) with an excess of sweetness, richness, or sentiment

The meaning of "cloy" is not restricted to taste, but used in context it does have the basic meaning of "taste bad."

An example of it used in relation to taste:

> Not everything works so well. Grilled octopus with potato is a bit dull. And a special of plump sweet diver scallops with vinegared rhubarb and white asparagus cream just misses the mark. The vanilla in the asparagus cream gives it a perceived sweetness that **cloys**.

[*LA Times*, "The Review: La Vida" by S. Irene Virbila (May 13, 2010)](http://www.latimes.com/food/la-fo-review-20100513-story.html)

Answer (score -1):

It's not a verb but maybe [pungent](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/pungent) [MW] would work for you

> having a strong, sharp taste or smell

Answer (score -1):

**gag**

> to experience the sudden uncomfortable feeling of tightness in the
>   throat and stomach that makes you feel like you are going to vomit

[Cambridge](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/gag?a=british)

Answer (score -2):

Not sure that there is a comparable word as 'taste' by itself (even in context) does not have an alternate meaning that implies unpleasantness. 'Smell' can imply unpleasantness.

Example:

"Something smells."
"Somethings tastes."

..and as an adjective can in fact imply pleasantness...

"That is smelly."
"That is tasty."

Comment: Hello, Brandad. 'I'm not sure there is such a word' is quite possibly as far as we'll get with this, but is better put as a comment.